# Run sed command every minute

Tags: linux, sed

I would like to run the following command every minute.

> sed 's/,,/, ,/g;s/,,/, ,/g' data.csv | column -s, -t

How would I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while : 
do 
 sed 's/,,/, ,/g;s/,,/, ,/g' data.csv | column -s, -t
 sleep 60
done
```

(You can fit it on one line if you use semicolons instead of newlines).

Watch is a nice program that encapsulates this loop:

```
watch -n 60  "sed 's/,,/, ,/g;s/,,/, ,/g' data.csv | column -s, -t"
```

(You need the double quotes here, since its not just a simple command but a whole pipeline that you want to repeat)

Comment: aah thanks! i was trying watch with single quotes. It worked with double. Thanks a ton!

Comment: You're welcome. You can't use single quotes since the thing you're trying to quote already has single quotes in it. In this case, you can swap them too, if you want to.

Answer (score 3):

You could also run that command as a cronjob. E.g. you can put it into a script.sh file and run it every minute by adding the following via `crontab -e`:

```
* * * * * /path/to/script.sh
```